# Sql query to fetch multiple data from multiple tables

Tags: mysql, sql

Given the following tables:

• Clients (ClientId, Name, Surname, Age)

• Products (ProductId, Name, Price)

• Purchases (Purchaseld, Date, ClientId, Productid)

I need to write  an SQL query that shows the quantity of purchases made by clients. It must only show the clients who made more than 1 purchase. The result should contain the following fields: Full name (i.e. "john rambo"), Quantity of purchases.

I have written this query but results are not coming correct

```
SELECT Concat(clients.name, clients.surname) 
FROM   clients 
       JOIN products 
         ON clients.name = products.name 
       JOIN purchases 
         ON products.productid = purchases.productid 
GROUP  BY clientid 
HAVING Count(clientid) > 1
```

Comment: What do you see instead of what you expect?

Comment: `clients.name = products.name` this looks strange

Comment: *I have written this query but results are not coming correct* The only result which can be produced by your query in its primay state (before M Khalid Junaid's edition) is "Syntax error".

Comment: Can you provide a https://www.db-fiddle.com/ ? so we could easily play with your datas.

Comment: The table `Products` not needed to be used in described task. Join `Clients` and `Purchases` (use correct columns for joining), group by client and count purchases (not clients).

Comment: You typically `GROUP BY` the same columns as you `SELECT`, _except those who are arguments to set functions_.

Comment: Hey John, you should provide more details related to your DB schema such as relationships and data types of your columns. It is easier for everyone to help you out that way.

Comment: Now its working i changed some lines of steps by analyzing the comments  its working thanks all of you for help

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT Concat(clients.name, ' ', clients.surname),
       count(*) as number_of_orders
FROM   clients 
       JOIN purchases 
         ON products.productid = purchases.productid 
GROUP  BY Concat(clients.name, ' ', clients.surname) 
HAVING Count(clientid) > 1
```

As noted in the comments, your join to products doesn't make much sense - your asking to only return records where there's a product that matches a client's first name.

CONCAT will glue the two fields together (e.g. "JohnRambo")

Comment: SELECT Concat(clients.name, ' ', clients.surname),
       count(*) as number_of_orders
FROM   clients 
       JOIN purchases 
         ON Clients.clientid=Purchases.clientid 
GROUP  BY clientid 
HAVING Count(clientid) > 1

Answer (score 0):

> It must only show the clients who made more than 1 purchase.

Your question has no mention of products, so there is no need for that in the query:

```
SELECT CONCAT(c.name, c.surname) 
FROM clients c JOIN
     purchases p
     ON p.ClientId = c.ClientId 
GROUP  BY c.ClientId, CONCAT(c.name, c.surname) 
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1 ;
```

Note that the `ClientId` presumably uniquely defines the clients -- not the names.  So the `ClientId` should be part of the aggregation.